# How to convert LIst<Object> to Map<K, V> with using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert `List<ObjectInList>` to `Map<K, V>`

```
class ObjectInList {
    List<Long> listWithLong;
    Map<String, Object> dataMap; // there is 'id' key, and i want to use this id as key in map to be converted
}
```

The new map format is like below

```
String type; // this type is value of dataMap.
List<Long> contents
```

each Object in `List<Object>` can have duplicated type

for example

```
///////// before converted ////////////
[
 {
    list: [1,2,3],
    dataMap: {
      type: "a",
    }
 },
 {
    list: [4,5,6],
    dataMap: {
      type: "b",
    }
 },
 {
    list: [7,8],
    dataMap: {
      type: "a",
    }
 },
]
///////////// after converted //////////
{
  "a": [1,2,3,7,8],
  "b": [4,5,6]
}
```

Comment: And each Map contains a single entry?

Comment: I think your model should be `DateType dataMap;` and `class DateType{ private String type}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupingBy` to group by `type` and `flatMapping` to flatten list of `Long` data and collect as single list.

```
Map<String, List<Long>> res = 
   objectInList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                       e -> e.getDataMap().get("type"),
                       Collectors.flatMapping(
                                  e -> e.getListWithLong().stream(),
                                  Collectors.toList())
     ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you need `Map<String, Object> dataMap;` when it was supposed to have only one value. For simplicity, I have modified your `ObjectInList` class as

```
class ObjectInList {
  List<Long> listWithLong;
  String type; 
}
```

To get grouped list we can do -

```
Map<String, List<Long>> grouped =
    objectInLists.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                ObjectInList::getType,
                ObjectInList::getListWithLong,
                (oldList, newList) -> {
                  oldList.addAll(newList);
                  return oldList;
                }));
```

**Explanation:**

`toMap` method -

```
public static <T, K, U>
    Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                    BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

`toMap` takes `keyMapper` which is `ObjectInList::getType` (to group based on type) and valueMaper is `ObjectInList::getListWithLong`and as we have duplicate key we need to provide a `mergeFunction` as `(oldList, newList) -> {oldList.addAll(newList);return oldList;}`

From documentation -

> a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated
> with the same key, as supplied to {@link Map#merge(Object, Object,
> BiFunction)